# Run script in background

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

I want to run following script as scheduled task on Windows 7 in background. Now, script displays cmd window and, can I run script without visible cmd window?

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell, oExec
Dim RegexParse
Dim hasError : hasError = 0

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set RegexParse = New RegExp

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%comspec% /c echo list volume | diskpart.exe")

RegexParse.Pattern = "\s\s(Volume\s\d)\s+([A-Z])\s+(.*)\s\s(NTFS|FAT)\s+(Mirror|RAID-5)\s+(\d+)\s+(..)\s\s([A-Za-z]*\s?[A-Za-z]*)(\s\s)*.*"

While Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    Dim regexMatches
    Dim Volume, Drive, Description, Redundancy, RaidStatus
    Dim CurrentLine : CurrentLine = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine

    Set regexMatches = RegexParse.Execute(CurrentLine)
    If (regexMatches.Count > 0) Then
        Dim match
        Set match = regexMatches(0)

        If match.SubMatches.Count >= 8 Then
            Volume      = match.SubMatches(0)
            Drive       = match.SubMatches(1)
            Description = Trim(match.SubMatches(2))
            Redundancy  = match.SubMatches(4)
            RaidStatus  = Trim(match.SubMatches(7))
        End If

        If RaidStatus <> "Healthy" Then
            hasError = 1
            'WScript.StdOut.Write "WARNING "
            MsgBox "Status of " & Redundancy & " " & Drive & ": (" & Description & ") is """ & RaidStatus & """", 16, "RAID error"
        End If
    End If
Wend

WScript.Quit(hasError)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not when using `Exec` to launch a `CMD` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** - If the task is running under your user credentials (if not, msgbox will not be visible)

There are two possible sources for the cmd window.

a) The script itself. If the task is executing `cscript`, the console window will be visible, avoid it calling `wscript` instead

b) The `Shell.exec` call. The only way to hide this window is to start the calling script hidden. On start of your script test for the presence of certain argument. If not present, make the script call itself with the argument, using `Run` method of the WshShell object, and indicating to run the script with hidden window. Second instance of the script will start with the special parameter, so it will run, but this time windows will be hidden.

**Option 2** - Running the task under system credentials.

In this case, no window will be visible. All will be running in a separate session. BUT msgbox will not be seen. Change `MsgBox` call with a call to `msg.exe` and send a message to current console user.